# Unable to redirect to my local page in asp dot net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am new to `asp.net core`. I have used [Identity](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/registration-and-login-functionality-in-asp-net-core-3-0-mvc-web-application-usi/) for login and registration. I am trying to redirect to my page after successful login.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = Url.Content("~/Home/Index");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
```

Below is my startup file in which I have done some configurations

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

**Update 1**

Below is my `Login.cshtml.cs`

```
namespace DemoLogin.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<DemoLoginUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<DemoLoginUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<DemoLoginUser> signInManager, 
        ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
        UserManager<DemoLoginUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }

        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
}
```

I have registered a user and then tried to log in it. But I am not redirecting to my page `~/Home/Index`

Comment: Is it logging in successfully?

Comment: @NeutralHandle yes it is logging successfully

Comment: Redirect doesnt work with post.

Comment: @NeutralHandle ok then what to do ?

Comment: Build the appropriate content without redirecting.

Comment: Or redirect from the client after a successful response... [I'm reading up on the topic a bit myself as I don't have a full understanding,and have opted for post-redirect get before which this behaviour would seem to prevent.]

Comment: @NeutralHandle I am also wondering why the provided tutorial haven't mentioned this

Comment: You are not redirected to the Index page. What did you return after successfully logging in? I built a new Identity project with the same code as yours and successfully redirected to the Index page.

Comment: @Moeez,Can you share us what you returned after successfully logging in?

Comment: @Yinqiu It's already in the question. I am trying to return this `returnUrl = Url.Content("~/Home/Index");`

Comment: @Moeez,What I want to ask is what the interface returns after successful login in your browser.

Comment: @Yinqiu at successful login the same `login` page is redirected

Comment: @Moeez,You can change the order of your `app.UseAuthorization();app.UseAuthentication();` like `app.UseAuthentication();app.UseAuthorization();`,then perform a few hard refreshes of your browser.

Comment: @Yinqiu by doing this I am unable to see my login page

Comment: @Moeez,The order of them is important. Besides, can you share all the code of your`Login.cshtml.cs` and whether there is `[AllowAnonymous]` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know the problem, did you add the `[Authorize]` attribute to your Index method?

Here is the solution.

change the order to:

```
     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseAuthorization();
```

Show off:
[image]

Since there are a lot of errors in your project, I suggest you create a new project and follow my steps. It is very simple.

Step1:(change the `Authentication`):

[image]

Step2:(Click the project `Add` and then click `New Scaffolded Item`.):

[image]

Step3:(chooes Identity then add):

[image]

Step4(override all files then add):

[image]

Last :migration and run project.Register first and then log in.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224417/discussion-on-answer-by-yinqiu-unable-to-redirect-to-my-local-page-in-asp-dot-ne).